# Vuejs How can I get a custom define object in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to use a custom object to instead of `vue-meta`

E.g.

```
<template>
  .....
</template>

<script>
export default {
  aboutMe: {}
}
</script>
```

**How to get the custom define object `aboutMe`.**

PS: But there is NOT `data` or `computed`

**Thank you!**

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Why not use `data` or `computed` to put `aboutMe` into?

Comment: I'm trying to get an object like `vue-meta`

Comment: What issue are you currently experiencing and how do you plan to use `aboutMe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is available in the [$options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options) property:

```
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$options.aboutMe)
}
```

or

```
<template>
   <span> {{ $options.aboutMe }} </span>
</template>
```

But generally you'd want to add the object to the [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data):

```
data: () => ({
  aboutMe: {}
})
```

Then you can use `{{ aboutMe }}` and `this.aboutMe`